# Нужно ли отделять "как книгу" запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

Посмотрел правила, касающиеся сравнительных оборотов с "как", но всё равно остаются сомнения. Предложение следующее:

*В таком состоянии можно читать своего противника(,) как книгу, определяя по характеру его движений намерения и желания.*

Здесь же "читать" использовано не в буквальном смысле, и запятую ставить не хочется. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласен с тем, что "запятую ставить не хочется". А почему?

Вот что отвечает [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20).

> **Вопрос № 297782**
> Читай его как открытую книгу. Нужна ли запятая перед как?
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Запятая не нужна. Не выделяются запятыми обороты с союзом *как*, если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо и Вам! Удачи!